# Using Restangular to call to the Google Calendar API to grab the JSON file to inject the calendar events using Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, google-calendar-api, restangular

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'restangular', 'ngRoute',      'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/GoogleCalID@group.calendar.google.com/events?key=API KEY');

$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });


})
;
```

Trying to use the baseurl and then call it in the controller but unable to gain access to the JSON data when called in this way

```
angular.module('myapp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function (Restangular) {

Restangular.all("items").getList();

 };
});
```

Any help on getting the request to not return on error would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/), it looks as if the base URL for the Google Calender API is `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3`.

So after updating your Restangular reference to the baseUrl, your calls would look something more like this.

```
Restangular.one('/users/me/calendarList').getList().then(function(calendarList) {
    //Do something with calendarList
});
```

Or something similar. You would need to [reference the docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/) for other valid endpoints.

If you need to send a query param with every request then you can use [setDefaultRequestParams](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setdefaultrequestparams) for that purpose.

Comment: This is close to what I needed, I will add the code that helped in a little, I am now struggling with the actual promise data that is being returned, I can see it but I cannot use it in the HTML via the main controller for some reason